# How to get Unique record with repsect to Date in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

Here is my table:

```
server  database  %full     Alert date
Server1 model     80.89 12/22/14 8:08 AM
Server1 tempdb    90.65 12/23/14 12:07 PM
Server1 Rep       80.33 12/4/14 8:06 AM
Server2 DB1       99.98 12/15/14 8:07 PM
Server2 DB1       99.99 12/15/14 8:07 PM
Server2 DB1       99.99 12/15/14 8:07 PM
Server2 DB2       95.2  12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server2 DB2       91.6  12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server2 DB1       98.57 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server2 DB1       98.49 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server2 DB1       98.17 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server2 DB1       97.72 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 DB1       97.86 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 DB1       88.56 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 DB1       88.48 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 DB2       89.25 12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 DB2       89.1  12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 tempdb    90.76 12/29/14 8:07 PM
Server3 tempdb    90.77 12/29/14 8:07 PM
Server3 tempdb    90.77 12/29/14 8:07 PM
Server3 tempdb    90.75 12/29/14 8:07 PM
```

I want to count of database full  alerts on each server for a period of time. I expect result like this:

```
server  database    %full   Alert date
Server1 model     80.89   12/22/14 8:08 AM
Server1 tempdb    90.65   12/23/14 12:07 PM
Server1 Rep       80.33   12/4/14 8:06 AM
Server2 DB1       99.99   12/15/14 8:07 PM
Server2 DB1       95.2    12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server2 DB2       91.6    12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 DB1       88.48   12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 DB2       89.25   12/29/14 6:06 AM
Server3 tempdb    90.75   12/29/14 8:07 PM
```

I'm using below query:

```
SELECT  x.RowNo,server_Name, Database_Name,Percent_full,notification_count,Alert_date
FROM 
(
    SELECT F.server_Name, Database_Name,Percent_full,notification_count,F.Alert_date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F.Alert_date ORDER BY F.server_Name DESC) AS RowNo
       --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F.server_Name ORDER BY F.Alert_date DESC) AS RowNo1
    FROM 
    tbl1 D 
    INNER JOIN tb12 F ON D.Logicalservername = F.Server_Name
    WHERE DBPlatformCode = 'SQL' and environmentcode ='PROD'
    and F.Alert_Date between '12-01-2014' and '12-31-2014'
    --and F.server_Name='LOUSASWPS02'       
) x
WHERE x.RowNo = 1 
order by server_name
```

However there are few database name common across servers so am not able to get exact notification count.

**Note: Those duplicate values are corresponding to each data file in the database**

Comment: I hope this record is wrong `Server2 DB1  95.2   12/29/14 6:06 AM` in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `window function` to

```
Row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY server_Name, Database_Name, F.Alert_date
            ORDER BY F.Percent_full )
```

In `partition by` you need to add `server_Name, Database_Name, F.Alert_date` and in `Order by` use `Percent_full`

change your query like this..

```
SELECT x.RowNo,
       server_Name,
       Database_Name,
       Percent_full,
       notification_count,
       Alert_date
FROM   (SELECT F.server_Name,
               Database_Name,
               Percent_full,
               notification_count,
               F.Alert_date,
               Row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY server_Name, Database_Name, F.Alert_date ORDER BY F.Percent_full ) AS RowNo
        FROM   tbl1 D
               INNER JOIN tb12 F
                       ON D.Logicalservername = F.Server_Name
        WHERE  DBPlatformCode = 'SQL'
               AND environmentcode = 'PROD'
               AND F.Alert_Date BETWEEN '12-01-2014' AND '12-31-2014'
       --and F.server_Name='LOUSASWPS02'       
       ) x
WHERE  x.RowNo = 1
ORDER  BY server_name
```